# MinGW can't find XInput.h header

Tags: c++, c, mingw, header-files

I am trying to compile this main.cpp file into a DLL with MinGW through a .bat file.
I am on Windows, not Linux btw.

compile.bat
 mingw\bin\g++ "srcdll\main.cpp" -O3 -DNDEBUG -s -shared -o "D:\CPP\output\main.dll"

but the compiler keeps saying it cannot find XInput.h. I have DirectX SDK installed as well and the include and lib directories are in my PATH environmental variable.

main.cpp

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <XInput.h>

#define EXPORTREAL extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) double __cdecl
#define EXPORTSTRING extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) LPSTR __cdecl

EXPORTREAL setRumble(double index, double left, double right)
{
    XINPUT_VIBRATION vibration;

    vibration.wLeftMotorSpeed = left;
    vibration.wRightMotorSpeed = right;

    XInputSetState(index,&vibration);

    return index;
}

EXPORTREAL leftTrigger(double index)
{
    XINPUT_STATE state;

    XInputGetState(index,&state);
    return state.Gamepad.bLeftTrigger;
}

EXPORTREAL rightTrigger(double index)
{
    XINPUT_STATE state;

    XInputGetState(index,&state);
    return state.Gamepad.bRightTrigger;
}

EXPORTREAL leftThumbX(double index)
{
    XINPUT_STATE state;

    XInputGetState(index,&state);
    return state.Gamepad.sThumbLX;
}

EXPORTREAL leftThumbY(double index)
{
    XINPUT_STATE state;

    XInputGetState(index,&state);
    return state.Gamepad.sThumbLY;
}

EXPORTREAL rightThumbX(double index)
{
    XINPUT_STATE state;

    XInputGetState(index,&state);
    return state.Gamepad.sThumbRX;
}

EXPORTREAL rightThumbY(double index)
{
    XINPUT_STATE state;

    XInputGetState(index,&state);
    return state.Gamepad.sThumbRY;
}

EXPORTREAL getButtonState(double index)
{
    XINPUT_STATE state;

    XInputGetState(index,&state);
    return state.Gamepad.wButtons;
}

EXPORTREAL checkButton(double index, double button)
{
    WORD buttonWord;
    XINPUT_STATE state;

    buttonWord = button;

    XInputGetState(index,&state);
    return (state.Gamepad.wButtons & buttonWord) ? 1 : 0;
}

EXPORTREAL getCtrlState(double index)
{
    XINPUT_STATE state;

    return XInputGetState(index,&state);
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    XINPUT_VIBRATION vibration;

    vibration.wLeftMotorSpeed = 0;
    vibration.wRightMotorSpeed = 0;

    XInputSetState(0,&vibration);

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding include path to the compiler's command line?

Comment: after some searching, I found that -I adds header files, so I did -I"D:\SDKs\DirectX\Include" and -I"D:\SDKs\DirectX\Lib" along with some #define __inout MS stuff, it seems it finds the files now but it throws errors like "Undefined Reference to XInputSetState@8" and the like...

Comment: Prefer `-isystem` when including system headers. This removes unwanted warnings from code that you are not going to modify anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add header path to the commande line
2. The error (undefined reference) come from the link. You should add path to .a/.o in the link line

Comment: You can add a path with -Lfolder/subfolder argmuent at the begining of the line. You can also, at the end of the line write the path to a .o (data\lib\xxx.a)